# appstats blocking urlopen()?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, urllib2, appstats

I'm trying to download some images using appengine, to create a document.

This is the line I get an error in:
`image_from_url = urllib2.urlopen(req)`

This is happening in a task from a push queue (deferred).

I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR    2016-07-26 12:34:05,388 base.py:214] descriptor '__dict__' for '_OxmlElementBase' objects doesn't apply to 'CT_R' object
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ariana/Desktop/SNC/illist/illistsite/handlers/base.py", line 36, in check_login
    return handler(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ariana/Desktop/SNC/illist/illistsite/handlers/docx_export.py", line 18, in get
    gcs_make_and_store_doc(self, data)
  File "/Users/ariana/Desktop/SNC/illist/illistsite/handlers/gcs_make_and_store.py", line 15, in gcs_make_and_store_doc
    store(self, make_doc(data))
  File "/Users/ariana/Desktop/SNC/illist/illistsite/handlers/gcs_make_and_store.py", line 144, in make_doc
    draw_logo(logo_run, company)
  File "/Users/ariana/Desktop/SNC/illist/illistsite/handlers/gcs_make_and_store.py", line 108, in draw_logo
    image_from_url = urllib2.urlopen(req)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 431, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1227, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1202, in do_open
    r = h.getresponse()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/dist27/gae_override/httplib.py", line 522, in getresponse
    **extra_kwargs)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/urlfetch.py", line 270, in fetch
    allow_truncated, follow_redirects, validate_certificate)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/urlfetch.py", line 347, in make_fetch_call
    rpc.make_call('Fetch', request, response, _get_fetch_result, allow_truncated)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 528, in make_call
    self.__service, method, request, response, self.__rpc)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 206, in Call
    function(service, call, request, response, rpc)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/appstats/recording.py", line 1441, in pre_call_hook
    recorder_proxy.record_rpc_request(service, call, request, response, rpc)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/appstats/recording.py", line 566, in record_rpc_request
    self.get_call_stack(trace)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/appstats/recording.py", line 879, in get_call_stack
    if not self.get_frame_summary(frame, trace):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/appstats/recording.py", line 937, in get_frame_summary
    x.set_value(format_value(value))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/appstats/recording.py", line 995, in format_value
    return formatting._format_value(val, config.MAX_REPR, config.MAX_DEPTH)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/appstats/formatting.py", line 250, in _format_value
    rep = _format_value(dct[nam], limit, level-1)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/appstats/formatting.py", line 203, in _format_value
    dct = getattr(val, '__dict__', None)
TypeError: descriptor '__dict__' for '_OxmlElementBase' objects doesn't apply to 'CT_R' object
```

When I disable appstats it works fine, but for some reason appstats is crashing it. Any suggestions or ideas of what the problem might be? I have googled the error and haven't found anything that seems at all similar. Thanks!

Comment: Please read [mcve] and try again.

Comment: @boardrider Edited